# What does "do following" blog mean?

Tags: blog

I read a SEO book, it talks about do following blog. Does it mean I can put anything on the blog which includes my link and talk about anything?

Comment: The book is most-likely written by one of the many sleazy "SEO professionals" out there who are little more than spammers. A lot of SEOers pretending to be whitehat have historically engage in and promoted comment spamming in order to game the search engines by creating external backlinks to themselves that artificially inflate their PR. It's basically equivalent to ballot stuffing. They talk about "do follow" blogs because comment links are supposed to be "nofollow", otherwise they invite this type of spammer.

Comment: BTW, I would stop reading that book ASAP. If you try to use these sleazy practices today, you'll most-likely be penalized by Google and other search engines for having a spammy link structure. In the recent year, the search engines have done a lot to combat this type of unethical "search engine optimization". In fact, there was so much fallout over the last Google update that many such SEOers began crying about the end of the SEO industry.

Comment: Good suggestion. Thanks. By the way, do you have any idea how to improve my website pagerank?

Comment: Good long-term SEO has no shortcuts. It's about regularly putting out quality content, promoting that content using legitimate means (pingbacks to relevant articles that you are responding to, authentic social media interaction with fans and thought leaders, advertising) and doing lots of coordinated cross-channel promotion (e.g. set up a youtube channel and occasionally promote your blog or twitter feed on it; set up a newsletter that informs subscribers of new blog articles or videos, but also providing exclusive content; running twitter contests that cross promote your facebook page, etc.).

Comment: Search engines like Bing and Google are starting to draw more ranking information from social media signals, especially with the rise in personalized searches. This means by having a solid social media presence and getting your content shared/liked via social media, your search ranking will increase. And of course, any kind of organic exposure will produce organic backlinks that will increase your PR. You can help this along by writing linkbait articles that people will want to link to from their own blogs/sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever it is you read was referring to blogs which did not set the `rel="nofollow"` attribute to links. Most likely within comment links, it does not necessarily mean that you can post a link and talk about anything.